# Stagewebview cannot re-select text content in IOS device- Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have the following problem.
Developing APPs on IOS using Flex 4.6

I am displaying parsed epub files into stagewebview. It works fine on the device. However, when I try to add the annotation tool which (likes the ibook annotation), I can only select one single word!! I tried the "Game of Flex" which it did the same way as loading a web content into a stagewebview component, and it cannot have control to select more word as well. Therefore, I think its the current limitation (correct me if there is actually a way to do that in stagewebview) on the stagewebview.

So, do you guys have other good ideas to display content as html without the limitation? like use other components, call JS? or use native object-c?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, never mind
This limitation is proved by Adobe, and it only happens on IOS.

We have 2 solutions:
replace the complete e-book component with HTML5 and integrate with native container.

replace the complete e-book component with Objective-C and invoke from Flex as native extension, an .ane file.

Might be good for people still struggling.

This is a simple tutorial from myself:
http://matthewhx.blogspot.com/

PS: My first stackoverflow question is answered by myself here : )